# How to upload Photos/ Images in Asp.Net 4.o Project

Tags: file-upload, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to add upload photo features in my MVC 4.0 Project, Please can you tell me how can I do that. I am using MVC 4.o and for Photo option i want to give **file / image upload**. Here is my Code

```
@model WebCart.Category

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Category", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))



{
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Category</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Photo)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input name="PhotoFile" id="File" type="file"/>
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}



    [HttpPost]
            [ValidateInput(false)]
            public ActionResult Create(Category category)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Categories.AddObject(category);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

                return View(category);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller action could take an additional `PhotoFile` argument:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Create(Category category, HttpPostedFileBase photoFile)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // you could manipulate the PhotoFile parameter here
        // for example let's store the uploaded file to a folder on the server
        if (photoFile != null && photoFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(photoFile.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), fileName);
            photoFile.SaveAs(path);
        }

        db.Categories.AddObject(category);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(category);
}
```

Or if you want to read the uploaded file as a byte array you could use the following:

```
byte[] photo = new byte[photoFile.InputStream.Length];
photoFile.InputStream.Read(photo, 0, photo.Length);
// Now you could assign the byte array to some property of your model
// and persist it into the database (even if this is a bad practice - 
// it would be more correct to store the photo on the file system and
// only store the full path to the photo in the database)
```

A must read article for uploading files in ASP.NET MVC is the following: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx